# Getting variable from texfield...what's wrong with my program?

Tags: php, variables, textfield

I'm practicing with PHP and tried to design a simple program.  If the user types "red" or "blue" into the textfield and hits "submit", the program is supposed to print "Your favorite color is red" or "Your favorite color is blue."  But for some reason it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     $favcolor = $_GET["favcolor"];

    switch($favcolor){
        case "red":
            echo "Your favorite color is red!";
            break;
        case "blue":
            echo "Your favorite color is blue!";

    }
    ?>
     <form action = "index.php" method = "post">
        <input type ="text" name="favcolor">
        <input type ="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

However, I get this error "Notice: Undefined index: favcolor in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fav_Colors\index.php on line 14"

What's the deal?

Comment: Why would you set the form to post and then check `$_GET`???
 Use `$_POST["favcolor"]`

Comment: Oh, my error.  I was just getting desperate and was changing things around.  But even when they are both "POST" or both "GET" its the same error.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Your point is correct, but, you missed the fact, that PHP will be executed independent of the submit button click and hence, the error will continue since, Favcolor is not set in the beginning. 

Either write the PHP code in a separate file or, enable the PHP code only when the onclick event on submit is triggered. 

Alternatively use a isset call to check if variable favcolor is  set and then display the line.

Comment: @UmashankarDas: No I didn't miss that, the duplicate addresses that but not the diff between post and get.

Comment: Okay, so I got rid of the error using "$fcoutput = "";"  followed by "$fcoutput = isset($_POST["fcinput"]);"  but now it always say "your favorite color is red" no matter what :/

Comment: @AbraCadaver If you check Dennis 's  comment, he is still getting the error even after a change from POST to GET

Comment: @UmashankarDas: No shit, the DUPLICATE answers the question.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  How do you close these questions?